# REST API controller/routes alongside normal html views

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a CakePHP app and would like to incorporate a simple REST API, at first just for GET requests without authentication.

I have the conventional structure, e.g.:

- Post (post model),
- postsController (posts controller), method names match the routes.
- views/posts (posts views - e.g. index.ctp etc)

Say I wanted a few REST API routes how would I add them alongside my normal views and controller methods. I presume having a separate `apiPostsController` might be a good idea but I'm not sure how to implement.

Route wise, for a given example.com/posts/view/123, the API equivalent might be example.com/api/v1/posts/view/123.

How might I implement this?

Looking at [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html), the given instructions make use of the conventional controller and views which are already in use for actually viewing the app.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need another controller? This is not DRY. You'll replicate a lot when you do this.

If your API methods behave that much different you can still use prefix routing and prefix the methods with api, for example: api_some_action().

I guess your API is using XML or Json, see this chapter of the book how to archive this along side the regular HTML views: [JSON and XML Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).

```
Router::connect('/api/:version/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    array(
        'version' => 'v1|v2',
    )
);
```

This route should work.

Comment: Many thanks. So, given I already have non-api methods (index, view, edit etc) would that mean I would need to prefix my api methods in the route? E.g. `/posts/api_view/123`

Comment: Read this section http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing  the route above works without prefix routing if you want to use prefix routing you'll have to adept it.